# Multiple Firebase App Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my project we have a sort of admin frontend app that manages data from children apps. Each child app has its own firebase database and the admin app has stored information on its own firebase database on how each child firebase app is structured and such. In addition, each client firebase app has its own Android and iOS clients that reads data from the realtime database.

The authentication on the admin app is done through username/password login and are only available to some pre-registered users.

The question is

**How can I properly authenticate the signed-in user on the  client apps? Is there a way to re-use the current ID Token to sign in to other apps?**

One solution I can think of is making a backend just to generate JWTTokens for each child app, but there should be an easier way to obtain what I want...

Comment: This may help, but I'm not sure: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html

Comment: I think that is very tied up with Google Sign-in authentication. I didn't see any options to whitelist anything on Firebase console for email/password authentication...

Answer (score 1):

Now you can have multiple apps in one Firebase project. That way, your users can easily sign-in and modify their User information in both apps.

*Note: Well, it's been more than a year since this question asked. But, hopefully you already found the answer.*